# Video Streamer that can connect via proxy

Tags: proxy

Hello I connect my phone to the internet via wifi, using connectify, my internet is via a proxy. I've managed to set wifi proxy, but this works for only the Internet app, my video players fail to stream, probably because they're going direct and not passing through the proxy.

My question is ; Is there a video player that works via proxy?

I'm not rooted.

Comment: Is rooting an option for you?

Comment: @MichaelK I've used a lot of tutorials to attempt rooting, but Wildfire S seems it can't be rooted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your proxy server is not blocking video streaming. If connectify is broadcasting an internet connection which is already established thru proxy, Android has got system-wide proxy connection. So, there's no need to setup proxy in particular player.
Sometimes, proxy servers limit the speed of video streaming & even block it. So, get this info first if proxy server is not managed by you.
Then, try using [Real Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.real.RealPlayer) & let me know..

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem, seems like the app tries to use ports other than HTTP specific ones, so your proxy server might be blocking them, that's why you probably might get connection errors, so simple way, try using Firefox browser it directs video stream via HTTP proxy. so how it works out for you Mob.